# hiding soft input in android app causes scroll view to scroll to bottom

Tags: android

I am hiding the android keyboard after a user finishes typing in an edittext field.  When I hide the keyboard, the entire view scrolls to the bottom.  How can I avoid this scrolling?

This is what I have for hiding the keyboard:

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(stepNameEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(stepDescriptionEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: why are you calling `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` twice?

Comment: there are two possible edittext windows that the user may have entered text into, so I call hideSoftInputFromWindow for both to ensure it gets hidden

Comment: iirc, you can call hide on any view, no matter which view currently has focus, and it will hide the keyboard

Comment: hmmm, i dont think its the hideSoftInput that is causing the scrolling, can you post more code? what is triggering the hideSoftInput to be called, and what happens after it is called?

Comment: also, do you have any flags set in your manifest regarding softInputMode? (ie `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`)

Comment: thanks a lot!  when I added the flag to the manifest, it doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to call `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` once, and try using `InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS` instead of "0" for the flag.

EDIT:
Try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your manifest.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I did remove one of the hideSoftInputFromWindow calls, but the scroll view is still scrolling to the bottom for some reason.